# FULL JOIN or 2 LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

First, I'm using PostgreSQL 9.1.20.

I have 4 tables (dp,dpo,ds,dso) with theses dependancies:

```
ds.dp_id=dp.id
dpo.dp_id=dp.id
dso.ds_id=ds.id
```

In other words:

```
dp have multiples ds entries (1,n);
dp can have multiples dpo entries or none (0,n);
ds can have multiples dso entries or none (0,n);
```

dso and dpo contains a common field (`option`) and sometimes dso.option=dpo.option
dso and dpo contains another common field (`value`) but dso.value is more relevant than dpo.value.

If the same "option" exists in the "dpo" table and the "dso" table, then the "value" of the dso is more relevant.
If the "option" only exists in the "dpo", then we take it.
If the "option" only exists in the "dso", then we take it.

I already tried this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM dp,ds,dso 
   FULL JOIN dpo USING (option) 
WHERE ds.id=1 
  AND dso.ds_id=ds.id 
  AND dpo.dp_id=dp.id;
```

It seems not working because dso and dpo can be null.

```
SELECT * 
FROM dp,ds,dso 
  FULL JOIN dpo USING (option) 
WHERE ds.id=1 
AND (dso.ds_id=ds.id OR dso IS NULL) 
AND (dpo.dp_id=dp.id OR dpo IS NULL);
```

Not working too.

Further more, maybe I should use `LEFT JOIN` for the "dso" to "ds" and "dpo" to "dp" dependancies...

```
SELECT * 
FROM (dp LEFT JOIN dpo ON dpo.dp_id=dp.id) 
   FULL JOIN (ds LEFT JOIN dso ON dso.ds_id=ds.id) ON (dso.option=dpo.option).
```

EDIT :
For a better view of the problem, there is an online diagram: http://hpics.li/3a934a3

PS: Sorry for my bad english... Trying to do my best.

Comment: Could you give some sample data and a desired result? I'm having a hard time following exactly what you're looking for as a result.

Comment: Your method of joining is very confusing, I'll work something up, but it's going to be difficult as your rules seem very convoluted.

Comment: `WHERE` clause may to refuse any 'outers' join (left, right, full) if it contains some filters related to outer joined tables. Move them to the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`. Also do not mix different kinds of joins (using `JOIN` and using `WHERE`).

Comment: You are mixing implicit joins and explicit joins. Don't do that.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I had some explaination in a diagram there : http://hpics.li/3a934a3
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I tried what I could try, even if it isn't the best way to achieve my goal. But now I'll try to use more explicit join.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a start:

```
select * from ds
join dp on dp.id=ds.dp_id
left join dpo on dop.dp_id=dp.id
left join dso on dso.ds_id=ds.id
```

Your question "dso and dpo contains a common field (option) and sometimes dso.option=dpo.option dso and dpo contains another common field (value) but dso.value is more relevant than dpo.value."

is not making sense to me. Based upon the question we cannot determine if multiple DPO and DSO records exist per dp and if multiple records exist for each "option" or "value".. it's very confusing.

I cannot tell from your question whether this part is trying to limit rows (IE adding something to the where or join clauses) or if it's trying to interpret the data (using a case, or "if", statement in the select)

Comment: And then he probably needs `COALESCE(dso.option, dpo.option)` to get his best match.

Comment: Thought about that, but he mentioned a criteria about them being equal or not equal, so I thought it might wind up being a "case" in the end.